# The type or namespace name 'TEntity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in .NET CORE And vs 2019

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

i face this error , when i create `IRepository` and create Repository inherit of  `IRepository`

i  have error in it

[image: error]

and i declaration `IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class` 
why this error

Thanks :)

Comment: Add the type parameter to the Repository as well

Comment: I think you need to do `Repository<TEntity> ...`.

Comment: I Create Repository and interface IRepository but issue in TEntity ، why error in this class although this generic class not make error in interface why do error in class library

Comment: i create that in IRepository and i dont have any error public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class

Comment: @eman: I don't know what you mean by "i create that in Irepositry" - but just because the interface is generic doesn't mean that everything implementing it is automatically generic. (For example, `StringComparer` implements `IComparer<string>`, but isn't generic in itself.) Additionally, please show code as *text* in your question - including a screenshot to show the locations of the errors is fine, but it would still be clearer to include the code as text as well.

Comment: `public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        TEntity Get(int Id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderby = null,
                string includeProperties = null
            );

        TEntity FirstOrDefault(
               Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
               string includeProperties = null
            );
    }`

Comment: public class Repository : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
       
        public TEntity Get(int Id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>, System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderby = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }  
    }

Comment: @Jon Skeet : the last two comment my code in IRepository (interface) and Repository (class) what is the problem in class ?? to have error
**Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations**

Comment: Please don't put code in *comments* - edit your *question*. And the answer is exactly as I said before - your class isn't generic. Make it generic as I showed in my answer, and all will be well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class isn't generic - it doesn't have any type parameters. What do you expect TEntity to refer to?

I suspect you intended to make your repository class generic too:

```cs
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

At this point, `TEntity` is a type parameter, and can be used as a type argument to `IRepository<>`, in the generic constraint, and in your constructor.

Comment: **This is my IRepository   **                                                                                   
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        TEntity Get(int Id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderby = null,
                string includeProperties = null
            );

       
        IList<TEntity> Getalllist();}

Comment: @eman: That's information that should be in the question, but I don't see how it's relevant to my answer. Just because the repository is generic doesn't mean that implementations are implicitly generic.